# Issue building OpenCV with ccache and CUDA

Tags: opencv, ccache

Trying to build OpenCV 3.3.1 with CUDA support, using `ccache`:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- OpenCV 3.3.1
- CUDA 8.0
- CCACHE 3.2.4

[image: pic]

Make fails for `.cu` files, giving error:

> /usr/bin/ccache: invalid option -- 'E'
>
> Usage:
>
> ccache [options] ...

I've added the `/usr/lib/ccache` to `PATH`, `which cc` and `which c++` outputs `/usr/lib/ccache/cc` and `/usr/lib/ccache/c++` respectively. Manually added a symlink for `nvcc` in `/usr/lib/ccache` directory, but now OpenCV CMakeLists.txt cannot find CUDA.

[image: pic]

But interestingly I can build [this sample](https://pastebin.com/ny87pYze) CUDA code, with this [CMake file](https://pastebin.com/WaCqz335) without any issue.

I've searched the net and read most posts on SO and other forums, but had no success. I've had this issue for previous versions of OpenCV as well, but always disabled `ccache` as a solution.

**Can someone please explain the reason behind this error?**

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set
-DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda
seems to solve this problem for me.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue and already have set what you suggest. So this does not solve the issue.